# Cannot populate a repeater System.String' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: datasource, eval, repeater

I am trying to populate a simple ASP repeater from the database. The query works fine and returns several varchar type characters.Here is my code, any insight would help out a lot, im stumped.

**Front End**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <p> <%#  Eval("FormData")%> </p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Back End**

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = GetKudosList();
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }


        public List<string> GetKudosList()
        {
            using (IntranetEntities KudosContext = new IntranetEntities())
            {
                var jon = KudosContext.FormInstances.Where(u => u.WorkflowID == 1).Select(u => u.FormData).ToList();
                return jon;
            }

        }
```

Even if i just create a list object in the back end without touching the DB i still get the error below
*'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'FormData'*

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your linq statement--> you are selecting: .Select(u => u.FormData).ToList();

You will get a List of FormData type, which is probably type of String... (which causes the eval to fail. You are trying to eval property "FormData" on a simple string)

Either use your item as is without eval, or remove the select :

Option 1: 
You only need the FormData from your object:
Use the linq as is, change your repeater template:

```
<p> <%#  Container.DataItem %> </p>
```

Option 2: 
You need the whole object and you want to display properties from it,
Change your linq:

```
var jon = KudosContext.FormInstances.Where(u => u.WorkflowID == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you want to sent that much data over network when only single field item collection is required?

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't want only the FormData, but the whole item. If he only needs the FormData, I said he doesn't need the eval

Comment: tldr;.. the question is about error while using Eval() and answer should address the issue first. You don't need to guess you can discuss it with OP with comments. :)

Comment: I've addressed why he's getting that error in my first line.

Comment: +1ed you answer for adding more detailed explanation. My only point was not to recommend something that could lead to another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your linq query to select an anonymous type instead of string.

```
var jon = KudosContext.FormInstances
                      .Where(u => u.WorkflowID == 1)
                      .Select(u => new { FormData = u.FormData}).ToList();
```

Now you can use `DataBinder` to get the property name from anonymous type:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <p> <%# (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "FormData"); %> </p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the Support! I think your suggestions were correct altho they were not working for me. The string "FormData" was not binding to the object

```
<%# this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>
```